# Assigning values to a column based on presence of certain specific values in another column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table -

```
    Customer ID   |   Year    |    Category     |   Value
   ---------------|-----------|-----------------|----------
            100   |   2014    |    Poor         |      10
            100   |   2014    |    Mediocre     |      20
            100   |   2014    |    Brilliant    |      80
            100   |   2014    |    Poor         |      10
            100   |   2014    |    Brilliant    |      80
            100   |   2014    |    Naive        |      15
            100   |   2014    |    Exceptional  |     100
            100   |   2014    |    Neutral      |      40
            100   |   2015    |    Brilliant    |      80
            100   |   2015    |    Poor         |      10  
            200   |   2014    |    Exceptional  |     100
            200   |   2015    |    Neutral      |      40
```

Now I want to add an additional Column 'Score' to this table. The value in the column should be based on the 'Category' Column.

1. If the category column has Poor and Naive for a customer for a year
   then score = 10
2. If the category column has Poor and Mediocre for a customer for a
   year then score = 15
3. If the category column has Brilliant, Exceptional and Neutral for a
   customer for a year then score = 75

Overall, I have 6 such conditions

So the result table should be -

```
Customer ID   |   Year    |    Category     |   Value  |  Score
--------------|-----------|-----------------|----------|--------
        100   |   2014    |    Poor         |      10  |    15 
        100   |   2014    |    Mediocre     |      20  |    15
        100   |   2014    |    Brilliant    |      80  |    75
        100   |   2014    |    Poor         |      10  |    15
        100   |   2014    |    Brilliant    |      80  |    75
        100   |   2014    |    Naive        |      15  |    10
        100   |   2014    |    Exceptional  |     100  |    75
        100   |   2014    |    Neutral      |      40  |    75
        100   |   2015    |    Brilliant    |      80  |    NULL
        100   |   2015    |    Poor         |      10  |    NULL
        200   |   2014    |    Exceptional  |     100  |    Null
        200   |   2015    |    Neutral      |      40  |    Null
```

SQL fiddle table - 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470a7/1

Comment: I don't understand your desired results.   For Customer 100, Year 2014, why do you have 15 for the "Poor" rows instead of 10?   The customer has both Mediocre and Naïve in the same year (2014).

Comment: @TabAlleman for customer 100,year 2014, for poor, either 10 or 15 should work. I am going to take a distinct sum later so as long as the value 10 and 15 appears once in the score column, the work is done

Comment: @TabAlleman It's perfectly working for conditions 1 and 2. However it is failing for third condition. When we have to  identify from 3 column values. It is returning NULL

Comment: Check if it's because I had a typo on "Neutral".   Oh wait, there's another typo too.   I will fix it shortly.

Comment: I just edited and fixed the typos.   try it now.

Comment: @TabAlleman I had already fixed the neutral typo. What was the other typo you were referring to?

Comment: After the subquery, I had "=75" instead of "=3 THEN 75".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it then:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
    WHEN Category = 'Poor' AND EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM Table t1
      WHERE t1.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
      AND t1.Year=t.Year
      AND t1.Category='Naive'
    ) THEN 10
    WHEN Category = 'Naive' AND EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM Table t1
      WHERE t1.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
      AND t1.Year=t.Year
      AND t1.Category='Poor'
    ) THEN 10
    WHEN Category = 'Poor' AND EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM Table t1
      WHERE t1.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
      AND t1.Year=t.Year
      AND t1.Category='Mediocre'
    ) THEN 15
    WHEN Category = 'Mediocre' AND EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM Table t1
      WHERE t1.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
      AND t1.Year=t.Year
      AND t1.Category='Poor'
    ) THEN 15
    WHEN Category IN ('Brilliant','Exceptional','Neutral') AND (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Category) FROM Table t1
      WHERE t1.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
      AND t1.Year=t.Year
      AND t1.Category IN ('Brilliant','Exceptional','Neutral')
    )=3 THEN 75
  END AS Score
FROM Table t
ORDER BY CustomerID, Year
```